# Permission denied when python app tries to write log file into shared volume in docker

Tags: python, docker, logging, docker-compose

I'm trying to write a simple python application to run inside docker with non-root user and I want to log into a shared volume the log files.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  testapp:
    hostname: pythonapp
    container_name: pythonapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Rome
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./log:/home/pythonapp/src/log
```

docker build file

```
FROM python:3

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Create a user with given UID.
RUN useradd -m -u 5000 pythonapp
USER pythonapp
RUN id

RUN mkdir -p /home/pythonapp/src/log
RUN chown -R pythonapp:pythonapp /home/pythonapp 
WORKDIR /home/pythonapp/src

## copy from host to container files
COPY --chown=pythonapp:pythonapp . .

## install dependencies
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "/home/pythonapp/src/pythonapp.py", "-p", "8080"]
```

Before building the image I created log folder in host macchine.

```
mkdir log
ls -la
>>> drwxrwxr-x 2 tabita tabita 4096 ott  2 19:16 log

setfacl -m u:5000:rwx ./log

ls -la
>>> drwxrwxr-x+ 2 tabita tabita 4096 ott  2 19:16 log

getfacl log/
>>># file: log/
# owner: tabita
# group: tabita
user::rwx
user:5000:rw-
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Then I created the image using docker-compose

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -v
```

However, I get error here

```
pythonapp | /home/pythonapp/src
pythonapp | pythonapp
pythonapp | uid=5000(pythonapp) gid=5000(pythonapp) groups=5000(pythonapp)
pythonapp | Traceback (most recent call last):
pythonapp |   File "/home/pythonapp/src/ssh_honeypot.py", line 28, in <module>
pythonapp |     logging.basicConfig(
pythonapp |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 2003, in basicConfig
pythonapp |     h = FileHandler(filename, mode,
pythonapp |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1146, in __init__
pythonapp |     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
pythonapp |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1175, in _open
pythonapp |     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
pythonapp | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pythonapp/src/log/pythonapp.log'
pythonapp exited with code 1
```

**DEBUGGING**

I tried to get into the container and create a file in the log folder. I'm able to create one but from host system I can't see the created file.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your files with this script :

```py
# pythonapp.py
with open('/home/pythonapp/src/log/test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Hello world!")
```

It works very well only if `x` access is granted to user `5000`.

this permission is needed to go through log directory.

Regarding your output, permissions are currently `rw-`

```sh
getfacl log/
>>># file: log/
...
user:5000:rw-
...
```

As your procedure seemed exact, could you try again from this :

> log is under my working directory

1. Add rights for user with `UID:5000`:

   ```sh
   setfacl -m u:5000:rwx log
   ```
2. Check rights, `rwx` is required

   > I think --tabular is a good option to view ACL permissions

   ```sh
   getfacl --tabular log 
   # file: log
   USER   <myuser>  rwx     
   user   5000      rwx     
   GROUP  <myuser>  rwx     
   mask             rwx     
   other            r-x
   ```
3. pythonapp.py should be able to write under log directory:

   > docker-compose up --build

   ```sh
   Step 13/13 : CMD ["python", "/home/pythonapp/src/pythonapp.py", "-p", "8080"]
    ---> Using cache
   ---> fcd2afb9f961
   Successfully built fcd2afb9f961
   Successfully tagged so_testapp:latest
   Starting pythonapp ... done
   Attaching to pythonapp
   pythonapp exited with code 0
   ```

Comment: Thanks. This helped and worked. Could you please explain why X is required in setfacl -m u:5000:rwx log.

Comment: It is the ability to cd in this directory , . -------> ./log/. Please see this useful answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21253